# Guice - inject multiple data sources

Tags: java, dependency-injection, runtime, guice

Suppose, I have a number of data sources:

```
class SomeDataSource {

   SomeDataSource(Params params) {
     //..
   } 
}
```

I want to put them into `HashMap<String, SomeDataSource>`

```
public class SomeModule extends AbstractModule {

  public void configure() {

  }

  @Provides
  private Map<String, SomeDataSource> loadDataSourcesFromFile() {

    // read params from cfg file
    //..

    Map<String, SomeDataSource> dataSources = new HashMap<>();
    dataSources.put("source1", new SomeDataSource(params));
    dataSources.put("source2", new SomeDataSource(params));
    dataSources.put("source3", new SomeDataSource(params));

  }
}
```

..and inject to my **DAO** bean (which is singleton).

```
@Singleton
public class SomeDAO {

  @Inject
  private Map<String, SomeDataSource> dataSources;

  public doAction(String dataSourceId) {

    dataSources.get(dataSourceId). //..
  }

}
```

So, my questions is:

1. How to bind `Map<String, SomeDataSource>` to `SomeDAO` ?
2. How to change/reload injected data sources at runtime ?

Sorry, I'm a newbie in Guice.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the problem? Looks to me like the Map shpuld get injected when you create an instance of the dao ... you do have Guice.createInjector() in your main() method and add the producer as a module? If not: forget the datasources and start with the basic tutorials.

Comment: Unfortunately, the Map is not injected. Exception: Guice configuration errors: No implementation for java.util.Map<java.lang.String, my.package.name.SomeDataSource> was bound.

Comment: You do return the map in the @Provides method, right?

Comment: How do you plan on updating your map? Or what event would cause you to update the map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to change/reload injected data sources at runtime

First, in my option it would be a best practice to make sure the map is immutable. Allowing other modules change the state unbeknownst to the class is a form of code smell.

I've got two solutions:

**Solution 1**: Create a Provider an poll an instance of the map everytime you need to poll a datasource. The provider will be responsible for returning the most updated map of datasources.

Provider Example:

```
@Singleton
public class SomeDAO {

  @Inject
  private Provider<Map<String, SomeDataSource>> dataSourceProvider;

  public doAction(String dataSourceId) {

    dataSourceProvider.get().get(dataSourceId). //..
  }

}
```

**Solution 2**: An even better solution, but same idea, would be to create a class who's responsibility is to return the latest and most updated datasource based on a key (A map wrapper that keeps the map updated).

DataSourceManager Example:

```
@Singleton
public class SomeDAO {

  @Inject
  private DataSourceManager dataSourceManager;

  public doAction(String dataSourceId) {

    dataSourceManager.get(dataSourceId). //..
  }

}
```